# Show and hide multiple divs with timer

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, timer

I am trying to make a message box which will show the active messages, one at a time from a MySQL table. I dont know how many divs there will be as it can be any number of active messages in my database. Right now i have printed out the divs i need trough an ajax timer and a php script, this timer keeps querying the database every 20 seconds to check for new messages. My php script prints out divs like this:

```
include 'status.php';

$strings = Status::messages();
$i = 1;
foreach($strings as $string){
  print '<div id="'.$i.'">'.$string.'</div>';
  $i++;
}
```

This print a div complete with an id from 1 to x. Now i need a JavaScript function that can display one of those divs at a time. To get the total number of divs i do this:

```
var top_level_div = document.getElementById('messagecontainer');
var count = top_level_div.getElementsByTagName('div').length;
```

I cant figure out how to go from here.

edit:

Here is my ajax timer that load the messages:

```
ajaxTimer8 = new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('messagecontainer', 'includes/messagereloader.php', {
     method: 'get', frequency: 20, decay: 1,
     onSuccess : function() {
     pollCounter = 11;
     }
});
```

Comment: Where is the code that loads and displays your messages via AJAX? That's where your timer needs to be placed.

Comment: should a random div be displayed, or all one after each other???

Comment: @hereandnow78 all one after each other would be the best.

Comment: mh, im not certain about what you really want to do. append all divs to the message-container? and then? show 1 div, wait x seconds and show the next div???

Comment: I have x number of divs inside a messagecontainer div. I want to start  by showing the first div, then wait 15 seconds and show the second div , wait another 15 seconds and show the next an so on...

Comment: Sorry posted the answer wrong which is meant for another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, i tried to simulate that the divs are already there:

```
<div id="messagecontainer">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>​
```

the divs inside the messagecontainer are per default hidden (display none):

```
// in your css
#messagecontainer > div {
  display: none;
}​
```

now in our script we create a interval which runs every 15 seconds, sets the previous div to display none, and the current div to display block:

```
var top_level_div = document.getElementById('messagecontainer')
  , divs = top_level_div.getElementsByTagName('div')
  , counter = 0
  , interval = window.setInterval(function() {

      // hide the previous div if it exists (counter > 0)
      if(divs[counter - 1]) {
          divs[counter - 1].style.display = "none";
      }

      // set the current div visible
      divs[counter].style.display = "block";
      counter += 1;

      // have we finished all divs? then clear the interval
      if(counter === divs.length) {
         window.clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 15000); // run that every 15 seconds​
```

see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZY4Vb/2/